# Show trigger log (queue) in Postgre via DataGrip

Tags: postgresql, triggers, datagrip

I have more then 30 triggers and 100+ tables in my DB. Insert 1 row into 1 table calls cascade of triggers in some tables. How can i render queue of trigger calling or get some log? I have an issue with cyclycal call and missunderstand how to debug it.

DataGrip 2023.1.2, Build #DB-231.9011.35, built on May 16, 2023

PostgreSQL 15.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

I tryed to find an answer in google and datagrip support. Unsuccess

Answer (score 0):

Add `RAISE WARNING` or `RAISE NOTICE` calls to you trigger functions. Then check your logs. You can include the original query text as part of the message if that would be helpful.